# basic web service not working

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I recently upgraded from windows 7 starter to windows 7 home premium because I want to begin testing my website but when I typed localhost in the url space on my browser I didn't get the iisstart page but rather the following error message:

Could not load type 'System.Web.Services'.

I tried going to the iis manager but everything there seemed fine.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what the binding paths are by using [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and the basic steps outlined in [this blog entry.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx)  It sounds to me like a permissions issue or a misplace file reference.  It could also be that there is a version issue not covered by the assembly manifest, so installing the latest available patches/updates could help as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit, I am new to this; your solution implies to me that I have to access some sort of .NET related process, but my pc is a simple one.  I was under the impression that once I upgraded from Windows 7 Starter I would authomatically have server capabilities so I could test my site; I paid for the upgrade and still I have no server functionality.